# How do I show the Empathy icon in the menu bar's notification area?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, empathy

I removed the default mail notification drop down since I only use an IM client, and don't want to have to go through an extra menu to get to it. After removing it, I tried the Empathy preferences and found no indication of how to get it to show up in the notifications area. Does anyone know how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may be interested in [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/438329) bug report at Launchpad.

It's not a bug, though.

The empathy icon was moved to the indicator applet. If you want to change this back to the old icon, go to "Edit-->Preferences-->Notifications Tab then uncheck "use message indicators"

Comment: I ended up just switching to Pidgin, but this looks right too.